# Decode Cookie variable extracted from a HTTP Stream - Python

Tags: python, http, cookies, utf-8, base64

I am using python to send a request to a server. I get a cookie from the server. I am trying to decode the encoding scheme used by the server - I suspect it's either utf-8 or base64.
So I create my header and connection objects.

```
resp, content = httpobj.request(server, 'POST', headers=HTTPheader, body=HTTPbody)
```

And then i extract the cookie from  the HTTP Stream

```
cookie= resp['set-cookie']
```

I have tried `str.decode()` and `unicode()` but I am unable to get the unpacked content of the cookie.

Assume the cookie is

> MjAyMTNiZWE4ZmYxYTMwOVPJ7Jh0B%2BMUcE4si5oDcH7nKo4kAI8CMYgKqn6yXpgtXOSGs8J9gm20bgSlYMUJC5rmiQ1Ch5nUUlQEQNmrsy5LDgAuuidQaZJE5z%2BFqAJPnlJaAqG2Fvvk5ishG%2FsH%2FA%3D%3D

The output I am expecting is

> 20213bea8ff1a309SÉì˜t`LQÁ8².hÁûœª8<Æ
>   *©úÉz`µs’Ïö¶Ñ¸•ƒ$.kš$5gQIPf®Ì¹,8�ºèA¦IœöZ€$ùå% *ao¾Nb²¶ÁöÃ

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3
The `unquote` function is in the `parse` submodule

```
import urllib
import base64

cookie_val = """MjAyMTNiZWE4ZmYxYTMwOVPJ7Jh0B%2BMUcE4si5oDcH7nKo4kAI8CMYgKqn6yXpgtXOSGs8J9gm20bgSlYMUJC5rmiQ1Ch5nUUlQEQNmrsy5LDgAuuidQaZJE5z%2BFqAJPnlJaAqG2Fvvk5ishG%2FsH%2FA%3D%3D"""

res =  base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote(cookie_val))

print(repr(res))
```

For Python 2 the function is directly accessible

```
import urllib
import base64

cookie_val = """MjAyMTNiZWE4ZmYxYTMwOVPJ7Jh0B%2BMUcE4si5oDcH7nKo4kAI8CMYgKqn6yXpgtXOSGs8J9gm20bgSlYMUJC5rmiQ1Ch5nUUlQEQNmrsy5LDgAuuidQaZJE5z%2BFqAJPnlJaAqG2Fvvk5ishG%2FsH%2FA%3D%3D"""

res =  base64.b64decode(urllib.unquote(cookie_val))

print repr(res)
```

Output:

```
"20213bea8ff1a309S\xc9\xec\x98t\x07\xe3\x14pN,\x8b\x9a\x03p~\xe7*\x8e$\x00\x8f\x021\x88\n\xaa~\xb2^\x98-\\\xe4\x86\xb3\xc2}\x82m\xb4n\x04\xa5`\xc5\t\x0b\x9a\xe6\x89\rB\x87\x99\xd4RT\x04@\xd9\xab\xb3.K\x0e\x00.\xba'Pi\x92D\xe7?\x85\xa8\x02O\x9eRZ\x02\xa1\xb6\x16\xfb\xe4\xe6+!\x1b\xfb\x07\xfc"
```

Of course the result here is a 8-bit string, so you have to decode it to get the the string that you want, i'm not sure which encoding to use, but there is the decoding result using the unicode-escape (unicode literal) :

```
>>> print unicode(res, 'unicode-escape') 
20213bea8ff1a309SÉìtãpN,p~ç*$1ª~²^-\ä³Â}m´n¥`ÅBÔRT@Ù«³.K.º'PiDç?¨ORZ¡¶ûäæ+!ûü
```

Well Hope this can help .

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. Only thing I need to figure out is how to pass it into function as hex integer value. I am trying to implement the [Padding Oracle](http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2010/09/14/automated-padding-oracle-attacks-with-padbuster/) algorithm